# Moving from (bad) array[size] to array = new float[size]

Tags: c++, arrays, floating-point

I was writing a program for finding roots for a class, and had finished and got it working perfectly. As I go to turn it in, I see the document requires the `.cpp` to compile using Visual Studio 2012 - so I try that out. I normally use Dev C++ - and I've come to find it allows me to compile "funky things" such as dynamically declaring arrays without using malloc or new operators.

So, after finding the error associated with how I wrongly defined my arrays - I tried to fix the problem using `malloc`, `calloc`, and `new`/`delete` and well - it kept giving me memory allocation errors. The whole 46981239487532-byte error.

Now, I tried to "return" the program to the way it used to be and now I can't even get that to work. I'm not even entirely sure how I set up the arrays to work in Dev C++ in the first place. Here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

float newton(float a, float b, float poly[],float n, float *fx, float *derfx);
float horner(float poly[], int n, float x, float *derx);
float bisection(float a, float b, float poly[], float n, float *fx);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float a, b, derr1 = 0, dummyvar = 0, fr1 = 0, fr0;
    float constants[argc-3];
    //float* constants = NULL;
    //constants = new float[argc-3];
    //constants = (float*)calloc(argc-3,sizeof(float));
    //In order to get a and b from being a char to floating point, the following lines are used.
    //The indexes are set relative to the size of argv array in order to allow for dynamically sized inputs. atof is a char to float converter.
    a = atof(argv[argc-2]);
    b = atof(argv[argc-1]);

    //In order to get a easy to work with array for horners method,
    //all of the values excluding the last two are put into a new floating point array
    for (int i = 0; i <= argc - 3; i++){
        constants[i] = atof(argv[i+1]);
    }

    bisection(a, b, constants, argc - 3, &fr0);
    newton(a, b, constants, argc - 3, &fr1, &derr1);
    cout << "f(a) = " << horner(constants,argc-3,a,&dummyvar);
    cout << ", f(b) = " << horner(constants,argc-3,b,&dummyvar);
    cout << ", f(Bisection Root) = " << fr0;
    cout << ", f(Newton Root) = "<<fr1<<", f'(Newton Root) = "<<derr1<<endl;
    return 0;
}
// Poly[] is the polynomial constants, n is the number of degrees of the polynomial (the size of poly[]), x is the value of the function we want the solution for.

float horner(float poly[], int n, float x, float *derx)
{
    float fx[2] = {0, 0};
    fx[0] = poly[0];  // Initialize fx to the largest degree constant.
    float derconstant[n];
    //float* derconstant = NULL;
    //derconstant = new float[n];
    //derconstant = (float*)calloc(n,sizeof(float));
    derconstant[0] = poly[0];

    // Each term is multiplied by the last by X, then you add the next poly constant. The end result is the function at X.
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        fx[0] = fx[0]*x + poly[i];
        // Each itteration has the constant saved to form the derivative function, which is evaluated in the next for loop.
        derconstant[i]=fx[0];
    }

    // The same method is used to calculate the derivative at X, only using n-1 instead of n.
    fx[1] = derconstant[0]; // Initialize fx[1] to the largest derivative degree constant.
    for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++){
        fx[1] = fx[1]*x + derconstant[i];
    }
    *derx = fx[1];
    return fx[0];
}

float bisection(float a, float b, float poly[], float n, float *fx)
{
    float r0 =0, count0 = 0;
    float c = (a + b)/2; // c is the midpoint from a to b
    float fc, fa, fb;
    int rootfound = 0;
    float *derx;
    derx = 0; // Needs to be defined so that my method for horner's method will work for bisection.
    fa = horner(poly, n, a, derx); // The following three lines use horner's method to get fa,fb, and fc.
    fb = horner(poly, n, b, derx);
    fc = horner(poly, n, c, derx);

    while ((count0 <= 100000) || (rootfound == 0)) { // The algorithm has a limit of 1000 itterations to solve the root.
        if (count0 <= 100000) {
            count0++;
            if ((c == r0) && (fabs(fc) <= 0.0001)) {
                rootfound=1;
                cout << "Bisection Root: " << r0 << endl;
                cout << "Iterations: " << count0+1 << endl;
                *fx = fc;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (((fc > 0) && (fb > 0)) || ((fc < 0) && (fb < 0))) { // Checks if fb and fc are the same sign.
                    b = c; // If fc and fb have the same sign, thenb "moves" to c.
                    r0 = c; // Sets the current root approximation to the last c value.
                    c = (a + b)/2; // c is recalculated.
                }
                else
                {
                    a=c; // Shift a to c for next itteration.
                    r0=c; // Sets the current root approximation to the last c value.
                    c=(a+b)/2; // Calculate next c for next itteration.
                }
                fa = horner(poly, n, a, derx); // The following three send the new a,b,and c values to horner's method for recalculation.
                fb = horner(poly, n, b, derx);
                fc = horner(poly, n, c, derx);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Bisection Method could not find root within 100000 itterations" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

float newton(float a, float b, float poly[],float n, float *fx, float *derfx){
    float x0, x1;
    int rootfound1 = 1, count1 = 0;
    x0 = (a + b)/2;
    x1 = x0;
    float fx0, derfx0;
    fx0 = horner(poly, n, x0, &derfx0);
    while ((count1 <= 100000) || (rootfound1 == 0)) {
        count1++;
        if (count1 <= 100000) {
            if ((fabs(fx0) <= 0.0001)) {
                rootfound1 = 1;
                cout << "Newtons Root: " << x1 << endl;
                cout << "Iterations: " << count1 << endl;

                break;
            }
            else
            {
                x1 = x0 - (fx0/derfx0);
                x0 = x1;
                fx0 = horner(poly, n, x0, &derfx0);
                *derfx = derfx0;
                *fx = fx0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Newtons Method could not find a root within 100000 itterations" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So I've spent the past several hours trying to sort this out, and ultimately, I've given in to asking.Everywhere I look has just said to define as

```
float* constants = NULL;
constants = new float[size];
```

but this keeps crashing my programs - presumably from allocating too much memory somehow. I've commented out the things I've tried in various ways and combonations. If you want a more tl;dr to the "trouble spots", they are at the very beginning of the main and horner functions.

Comment: Remove the C tag.  This is clearly a C++ question.  Have you tried std::vector?  Compile at the highest warning level you can.

Comment: When your code is crashing and you're not sure why, **retreat**. If you can't get back to a working version, write `HelloWorld`. Then introduce a dynamic array ('float* constants = NULL; constants = new float[size];'). When that works perfectly, start reintroducing functions from your code above, fixing them as you go. Don't forget to test at every step and **never add to code that doesn't work.**

Comment: When using g++ , use the flags `-std=c++14 -pedantic` to get rid of as many non-standard extensions as possible. (If you have an old version you may need c++11 instead of c++14)

Comment: replace `float derconstant[n];` with `vector<float> derconstant(n);`

Comment: Use either `std::vector` for dynmaic arrays, or `std::array` for fixed-size arrays. THis solves a lot of your problems.

Comment: I am not sure this is C++ code. You allocate a dynamic array `float constants[argc-3];`, and I think this not supported in C++, only in C99(?). From the looks of your code, I would say this is more C than C++. You may find https://isocpp.org/tour and this https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines interesting.

Comment: *Now, I tried to "return" the program to the way it used to be and now I can't even get that to work* that should teach you to always work under source control (with git and the other DVCS that allow you to start a repository without setting up anything on remote servers there are really no excuses now)

Comment: @Jens it's a [GCC extension in C++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: So, after a few tweaks, I've narrowed my problem down to the bisection function. I haven't looked into it all the way yet, but I am still thankful for all the help. I would have used vectors for this, but not only were we never formally taught vectors - I was having trouble finding a simple way of re-implementing the entire program as vectors without basically having to do build all of my functions, alongside doing char to floating point from array to vector. Maybe this is easier than I thought, but it seems most of the problems are fixed now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: By the way, for future reference, if you use a version-control system on your code, it’s really easy to revert when you need to.  Also, were you able to put a breakpoint on the allocation and check the value of `size`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one issue, in main you allocate space for `argc-3` floats (in various ways) for `constants` but your code in the loop writes past the end of the array.

Change:

```
for( int i = 0; i<=argc-3; i++){
```

to

```
for( int i = 0; i<argc-3; i++){
```

That alone could be enough to cause your allocation errors.

Edit: Also note if you allocate space for something using `new`, you need to delete it with `delete`, otherwise you will continue to use up memory and possibly run out (especially if you do it in a loop of 100,000).

Edit 2: As Galik mentions below, because you are using `derconstant = new float[n]` to allocate the memory, you need to use `delete [] derconstant` to free the memory. This is important when you start allocating space for class objects as the `delete []` form will call the destructor of each element in the array.

Comment: I'll try that out once I get the chance. And I totally didn't catch the first bit there in the for loop. Thank you so much.